# Group of order $p^{n}$ has normal subgroups of order $p^{k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Q: Prove that a subgroup of order $p^n$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^{k}$ for all $0\leq k \leq n$.

Attempt at a proof: We proceed by Induction. This is obviously true for $n=1, 2$.
Suppose it is true for $m \leq n-1$. Now, take the group $G$ of order $p^{n}$. Since it is a $p$-group, it has a non-trivial center by the Conjugacy Class equation. This center then has a subgroup of $K$ order $p$ by Cauchy's theorem for example. Since this subgroup is contained in the center, it is normal in $G$.

Take the quotient $G/K$ which now has order $p^{n-1}$ hence by the induction hypothesis has subgroups $\bar{H_{k}}$ of order $p^{k}$ for $0\leq k \leq n-1$, which are normal in $G/K$. By the lattice isomorphism theorem, the lattice of $G$ has corresponding groups $H_{k}$ which are normal in $G$.

The index of each such subgroup is $|G:H_{k}|=|G/K: \bar{H_k}|=p^{n-1-k}$, hence $H_{k}$ has order $p^{k+1}$ in $G$ as desired.

Does this look okay?

Comment: Do it by induction. First consider the abelian case. Then consider the non abelian case, for this one after the base case, split by the center(I mean the quotient group $G/Z(G)$) and apply correspondence theorem.

Comment: Is there an error in what I wrote up there? The way I set it up it doesn't seem I need to split it into an abelian and non abelian case, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I don't think so. It seems quite well.

Comment: @DiegoRobayo Okay, I see what you mean though. If I take the center to be say order $p^{k}$ in there I have all the subgroups of order less $p^{m}, m\leq k$ since for Abelian groups it's easy to construct the subgroups, and then I still need to apply the correspondence theorem to $G/Z$ in the same way. Thanks :)

Comment: @TheManWhoNeverSleeps It looks just fine to me. Consider writing an answer to your own question so that it will not be contained in the "Unanswered Questions" section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems everyone agrees that this is fine, so I'm posting this in order for the question to be removed from the unanswered section.

Comment: You could make this post CW.

Comment: Well, by induction each $\bar{H_{i}}$ is normal in $G/K$. The 4th isomorphism theorem says that the lattices for $G$ above $K$ and that of $G/K$ are the same, and $\bar{H_{i}}$ is normal if and only if $H_{i}$ is normal. For example pg 99 of http://zeth.ciencias.uchile.cl/~cortiz/Apuntes/ebooks/Abstract%20algebra%20-%20Dummit%20and%20Foote.pdf   And sorry, what is CW?

Comment: Right. You can do this more generally for a group of any finite order and look at its Sylow subgroups. *Then* you can claim that the subgroups are normal in the Sylow, but not in all of $G$. My bad.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you asked. :)